# how to implement Gzip compressor for one endpoint in .NET core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I have a .NET core project `(EntityRelationship)` and enable the Gzip compressor for that project.

### Program.cs

```
using EntityRelationship.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.IO.Compression;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

...

builder.Services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
{
    options.EnableForHttps = true;
    options.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
});

builder.Services.Configure<GzipCompressionProviderOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Level = CompressionLevel.Optimal;
});


var app = builder.Build();

...

// Enable compression
app.UseResponseCompression();

app.Run();
```

In this case, the Compressor enable for whole endpoints in this project.

But I try to enable the compressor for specific endpoints.

***How to implement?***

I try to enable the compressor for specific endpoints.

How to implement?

Comment: Why do you wish to only use compression on a single endpoint?

Comment: Does my answer useful to you ? If you need further help, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the easiest approach is to use the ability to conditionally branch the execution pipeline with `UseWhenExtensions.UseWhen`:

> Conditionally creates a branch in the request pipeline that is rejoined to the main pipeline.

```cs
app.UseWhen(ctx => ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(...), // predicate to determine that compression should be used 
    appCond => appCond.UseResponseCompression());
```

Though I would argue that it should be just fine to enable it for all endpoints.

Comment: _"it should be fine to enable it for all endpoints." - Agreed. Not sure why OP only wants to enable this for a particular endpoint!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using middleware and it works fine. And I also try the solution provided by
`Guru Stron` and not works for me. You also can find the commented code in my Program.cs file.

#### My Test Result like below:

[image]

**GzipCompressionMiddleware.cs**

```
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;

namespace gzip
{
    public class GzipCompressionMiddleware 
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        public GzipCompressionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }
        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.Request.Path == "/Home/Privacy")
            {
                var acceptEncoding = context.Request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];

                if (acceptEncoding.ToString().Contains("gzip"))
                {
                    context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "gzip");

                    using (var gzipStream = new GZipStream(context.Response.Body, CompressionMode.Compress))
                    {
                        context.Response.Body = gzipStream;

                        await _next(context);

                        await gzipStream.FlushAsync();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    await _next(context);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await _next(context);
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression;

namespace gzip
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            //builder.Services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
            //{
            //    options.EnableForHttps = true;
            //    options.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
            //});

            // Add services to the container.
            builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            // Enable compression
            //app.UseResponseCompression();

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseMiddleware<GzipCompressionMiddleware>();

            //app.UseWhen(ctx => ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Home/Privacy"), // predicate to determine that compression should be used 
            //   appOptIn => appOptIn.UseResponseCompression());

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            // Enable compression
            //app.UseResponseCompression();

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```